# Remove function - link list

Tags: c, python-3.x, memory, free

I am learning link list in python, as I already have some knowledge of list in C . I have a question about removing nodes, the basis of the algorithms used in some exercises is this:

```
Algorithm remove_first(L): if 
    L.head is None then 
        Indicate an error: the list is empty.         
    L.head = L.head.next 
    L.size = L.size−1
```

I have questions about memory leakage. As the removal of nodes apparently only works with an exchange of pointers, my question is if the memory with this exchange is allocated and inaccessible or not, if the exchange already makes available the memory? As the function free of C, is there any similar method in python to make available the memory?

Comment: Python is a language with automatic memory management. As soon as some value becomes not reachable - it will be garbage collected at some point in time later.